# Shutting down the pc while the program being executed!

Tags: errors, miktex, editors, led-editor

My PC was turned off while I was running my TeX  file on the LED (LaTeX editor). Indeed, it turned off before the execution of the file was finished.
When I came back to my tex file it was turned into binary !!!

Can anybody know what is the reason, and is there a way to turn them back?

Comment: Are you referring to the `.tex` or the output?

Comment: The tex file!!!

Comment: Have you ever faced with such a problem?

Comment: No; and I'm surprised to hear this is what happens since (surely..?) the `.tex` file should just be read, not manipulated. But doesn't `LED` have default auto-save settings?

Comment: @jon unfortunately not. I'm surprised too. It is about 4 years I'm working with LED. I've never seen such a thing!!!

Comment: With multiple geographically dispersed authors, each with their own OS and toolset, we setup a git repo on Bitbucket and split the document into sections to minimize mutex problems.  This is useful for even a single author.  This was very helpful:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6188780/git-latex-workflow

Comment: Have you tried to reproduce this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately this happened to me with LEd and I don't think there is a fix for that. I would recommend not using LEd as an editor since the last bug fix is from 2009 (though it was a very nice one back then) and I've lost my documents more than twice with it.

Comment: @percusse Thank you so much... What Editor do you recommend? I'm realy accustomed to LED... Do you know any editor similar to LED?

Comment: IDE's are more personal choice I believe, hence please choose your's from [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339/15717), it's very nicely maintained thread. I have not used LED so no idea for an equivalent of it, may be (free ones)TeXworks/TeXmaker/TeXstudio... can do.

Comment: @Mamal I've been using TeXnicCenter 2 beta but others are also very satisfied with other editors so I think now it is safe to recommend all editors depending on your personal taste. Thaqt includes WinEdt if you don't mind popups once in a while. I've bought it for historical reasons(since I've wrote my MSc thesis with it) but use TC daily.

Answer (score 3):

Aparently, you have a **corrupted file system**.

Is desirable that you run a checkdisk.

Don't recover anything before that run, to avoid writing on sectors from files that can be recovered.

Denis J Navas

Answer (score 0):

The exact same problem happened to me and after 2 days of useless restoration of windows I noticed that latex backs up its files automatically.
in the same directory you had your file on look up yourfilename.sav or yourfilename.bak files. open either one of them on windows notepad. your latex file is right there waiting for you to copy and compile.
came 3 years later but good to know.

Comment: I'm not sure that latex is creating those files, more likely this is your editor.